# Passing large arrays from MainWindow to QDialogs

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

So, I am fairly new to QT and I have mostly coded in Java and Python, while this is in C++. I was wondering how I can pass a ~200 array of structs without having setFunctions within this dialog and calling them from my MainWindow with an instance of said QDialog. This is because my struct has a lot of data within it (around 50 strings) and copying it over sounds inefficient and a hassle. I also don't know whether I should make it an array of pointers to structs if that'd be the way to go. Heres my code:

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "tenseselectiondialog.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Japanese Conjugator 101");
    tenseSelection = new TenseSelectionDialog();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
    delete tenseSelection;
    delete conjugateDialog;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionQuit_triggered(){
    QApplication::quit();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_Qt_triggered(){
    QString about = "Hey! I am the creator of this program. I want to make the process of learning japanese faster for everybody so here is a program that uses spaced repition of japanese verb conjugation to improve your conjugating skills!";
    QMessageBox::information(this, "About Me", about);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_triggered(){
    QApplication::aboutQt();
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked(){
            MainWindow::hide();
            this->tenseSelection->setModal(true);
            this->tenseSelection->exec();
            MainWindow::show();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionContact_Me_triggered()
{
    QString contact = "If you notice any errors/bugs with the program itself or conjugations, please notify me at: tomasnew1@hotmail.com, and I will send out a patch ASAP!";
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Contact Me", contact);

}

MainWindow* MainWindow::get() {
    return this;
}
```

TenseSelectionDialog.cpp

```
#include "tenseselectiondialog.h"
#include "ui_tenseselectiondialog.h"
#include "conjugatedialog.h"

TenseSelectionDialog::TenseSelectionDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TenseSelectionDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Japanese Conjugator 101");
    conjugateDialog = new ConjugateDialog();
}

TenseSelectionDialog::~TenseSelectionDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}


void TenseSelectionDialog::on_continueButton_clicked()
{
    this->conjugateDialog->setModal(true);
    this->conjugateDialog->exec();
}
```

structs.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const string sampleFile = "Japanese verbs";
const string sampleExtension = ".txt";
const string samplePath = "";
const int VERBS = 500;
const int totalTenses = 14;

struct tenseType{
   string currentTense;
   string plainAffirmative;
   string plainNegative;
   string formalAffirmative;
   string formalNegative;
};

struct verbType{

    string verbStem;
    string verbInfinitive;
    string dictionaryFormRomaji;
    string dictionaryFormHiragana;
    string dictionaryFormKanji;
    string verbDefinition;
    int verbGroup;
    string verbEnding;

    tenseType presentTense;
    tenseType volitionalTense;
    tenseType imperativeTense;
    tenseType TaiTense;
    tenseType TaiPastTense;
    tenseType pastTense;
    tenseType pastPresumptiveTense;
    tenseType presentProgressiveTense;
    tenseType pastProgressiveTense;
    tenseType conditionalTaraTense;
    tenseType conditionalEbaTense;
    tenseType potentialTense;
    tenseType causativeTense;
    tenseType passiveTense;
};

void init(verbType verbArray[VERBS]);
void verbInit(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int &count, int flag, string fileName, string fileExtension = sampleExtension, string filePath = samplePath);
string removeSpaces(string str);
void printVerbs(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int count);

#endif // STRUCTS_H
```

functions.cpp

## include "structs.h"

```
void verbInit(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int &count, int flag, string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath){
     string fileLine;
     string secondLine;
     string thirdLine;
     string fourthLine;
     string fifthLine;
     string sixthLine;
     string seventhLine;
     ifstream myFile (filePath + fileName + fileExtension);
     int currentIndex = 0;
     int passingInt = 0;
     if (myFile.is_open()){
         while (getline(myFile,fileLine)){
             verbType verb;
             verbArray[currentIndex] = verb;
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbStem = removeSpaces(fileLine);
             getline(myFile,secondLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbInfinitive = removeSpaces(secondLine);
             getline(myFile,thirdLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji = removeSpaces(thirdLine);
             getline(myFile,fourthLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormHiragana = fourthLine;
             if (verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "motsu" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "matsu"){
                 verbArray[currentIndex].verbEnding = "tsu";
             }else if (verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "arau" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "tsukau" ||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "omou" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "utau" ||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "iu" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "morau" ||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "harau" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "kau" ||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "au" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "narau"||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "warau" || verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "suu" ||
                       verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji == "chigau"){
                 verbArray[currentIndex].verbEnding = "u";
             }else {
                 verbArray[currentIndex].verbEnding = verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji.substr(verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji.length()-2);
             }
             if (flag == 1) {
                 getline(myFile,fifthLine);
                 verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormKanji = fifthLine;
             }
             getline(myFile,sixthLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbDefinition = "to " + sixthLine;
             getline(myFile,seventhLine);
             passingInt = stoi(seventhLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbGroup = passingInt;
             currentIndex++;
             count++;
        }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
       if (verbArray[i].verbGroup == 1){
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "u" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "tsu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ru"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "tta";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "bu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "mu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "nu"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "nda";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ku"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "ita";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "gu"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "ida";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "su"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "shita";
           }
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunakatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunakatta";
           if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "u" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "tsu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ru"){
               verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "tte";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "bu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "mu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "nu"){
               verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "nde";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ku"){
               verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "ite";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "gu"){
               verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "ide";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "su"){
               verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "shite";
           }
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anai de kudasai";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "e";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "na";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "emasu";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "emasen";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "eru";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainNegative= verbArray[i].verbStem + "enai";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasu";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "iru";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasen";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imashita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "ita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "rou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "eba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anakereba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalAffirmative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "imashitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "ra";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "imasendeshitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anakattara";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "asemasu";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "asemasen";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "aseru";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "asenai";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "aremasu";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "aremasen";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "areru";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "arenai";

       }else if (verbArray[i].verbGroup == 2){
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ta";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "you";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takunakatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "takunakatta";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "te kudasai";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nai de kudasai";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ro";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "na";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "raremasu";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "raremasen";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "rareru";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainNegative= verbArray[i].verbStem + "rarenai";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasu";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "iru";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasen";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imashita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "ita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "rou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "reba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nakereba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalAffirmative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "mashitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "masendeshitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nakattara";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "sasemasu";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "sasemasen";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "saseru";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "sasenai";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalAffirmative;
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalNegative;
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainAffirmative;
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainNegative;

       }else {
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tta";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "tai";
           verbArray[i].TaiTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunai";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunakatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takatta";
           verbArray[i].TaiPastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "takunakatta";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem.substr(0, verbArray[i].verbStem.length()-1) + "tte";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanai de kudasai";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "e";
           verbArray[i].imperativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "na";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "emasu";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "emasen";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "eru";
           verbArray[i].potentialTense.plainNegative= verbArray[i].verbStem + "enai";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasu";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "iru";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasen";
           verbArray[i].presentProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imashita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "ita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].imperativeTense.formalAffirmative + "imasendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastProgressiveTense.plainNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "rou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "deshou";
           verbArray[i].pastPresumptiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative + "darou";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "eba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanakereba";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalAffirmative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalEbaTense.formalNegative = "N/A";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "imashitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative + "ra";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "imasendeshitara";
           verbArray[i].conditionalTaraTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanakattara";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wasemasu";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wasemasen";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "waseru";
           verbArray[i].causativeTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wasenai";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "waremasu";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "waremasen";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wareru";
           verbArray[i].passiveTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "warenai";
       }
   }
}

void printVerbs(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cout << "Verb Ending: " << setw(20) << verbArray[i].verbEnding << endl;
        cout << "Verb Form Pres " << setw(20) << verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative << setw(30) << verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative << endl;
        cout << "Verb Plain Pres " << setw(20) <<  verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative << setw(30) << verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative << endl;
        cout << "Verb Form Past " << setw(20) << verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative << setw(30) << verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative << endl;
        cout << "Verb Plain Past " << setw(20) << verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative << setw(30) << verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative << endl;

    }
}

string removeSpaces(string str)  {
    string placer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (!isspace(str[i])){
            placer += str[i];
        }
    }
    return placer;
}
```

I did not include my .h files as I did not have enough lines, just know my arrays are private members. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `void verbInit(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int &count, int flag, string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath)` -- I'll break the good news to you -- `verbType verbArray[VERBS]` is not an array, it is a pointer.  That function declaration is exactly the same as `void verbInit(verbType *verbArray, int &count, int flag, string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath)`

Comment: Yeah I realize that, I was just spacing out when typing. What I meant is to have an array of pointers to verbTypes, rather than an array of verbTypes. I still don't understand the best way to access the verbArray from MainWindow in TenseSelectionDialog though.

Comment: Please simplify your code by removing the bits that are completely unrelated to your arrays or data structures (for example, the "About" stuff in _MainWindow.cpp_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1a. Passing arrays efficiently

> my struct has a lot of data within it (around 50 strings) and copying it over sounds inefficient and a hassle.
>
> ...
>
> `void printVerbs(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int count);`

First, start using C++ containers like `std::vector` or `QVector` instead of raw C arrays. The C++ container classes are much easier to manage and debug.

Then, you can cheaply pass arrays around by **const reference**:

`void printVerbs(const QVector<verbType> &verbArray);`

*Note: You don't need to pass `count`! The vector knows how many elements it contains.*

This achieves 2 things:

- The **reference** part ensures that your data is not copied during the function call, because the function is *referencing* the data that already exists
- The **const** part ensures that the function cannot accidentally modify your existing data.

## 1b. Copying arrays without copying

`QVector` is implicitly-shared (also called "copy-on-write"): https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html This means you can pass a copy of `QVector<verbType>` from your `MainWindow` into your `TenseSelectionDialog` and even store a copy as a member variable in `TenseSelectionDialog`. As long as neither copy is modified, both vectors will share the same data internally.

Alternatively, if you guarantee that `MainWindow` will always outlive `TenseSelectionDialog`, then you can have `TenseSelectionDialog` store a pointer or reference to `MainWindow`'s member variable.

## 2. Using arrays-of-(pointers-to-structs)

> I also don't know whether I should make it an array of pointers to structs if that'd be the way to go.

Using an array-of-pointers is most useful if:

- **Your array will get modified or copied frequently.**

  - Inserting or removing elements can cause the array contents to be moved in memory.
  - It is cheaper to move/copy pointers than large structs.
- **Your array will be huge.**

  - Data in an array is stored in a *contiguous* memory block, given by `N * sizeof<ArrayElement>` where `N` is the number of elements.
  - If your memory is too fragmented, your PC might not have a large enough contiguous block of RAM to store the data.
  - For large structs, storing pointers reduces the amount of contiguous memory needed.

If these 2 criteria don't apply, then there's less benefit in using an array-of-pointers. *(Hint: ~500 elements is tiny)*

If you want to use an array-of-pointers, do use `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers so that you don't need to manage the memory explicitly.

## 3. (Other) String programming

If you're willing to use `QString` in your core logic, your string manipulation code could be simplified greatly.

Example:

> ```
> string removeSpaces(string str)  {
>     string placer = "";
>     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
>         if (!isspace(str[i])){
>             placer += str[i];
>         }
>     }
>     return placer;
> }
> ```

... could be replaced by

```
QString removeSpaces(QString str) {
    str.remove( QRegularExpression("\s") );
    return str;
}
```

...or you can just call `QString::trimmed()` if you only want to remove whitespace from the ends of the string.

`QString` is also unicode-aware (unlike `std::string`) so you can use it to store hiragana, katakana, and kanji in a platform-independent manner.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, really helpful and insightful!